# Exercise to verify if a word == it's reverse

Tags: c++

I've come into some problem with my code. At a first glance, it seems that I've done everything right and the code should work. But, it isn't. This exercise asks me to verify if a word is equal to it's reverse.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char cuv[255], cuv1[255]=""; cin>>cuv;
    int j = strlen(cuv)-1;
    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(cuv); i++)
        cuv1[i]=cuv[j-i];
    cuv1[strlen(cuv1)+1]='\0';
    if(cuv==cuv1)
    cout<<"cuvantul este palindrom";
    else
    cout<<"cuvantul nu este palindrom";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(cuv==cuv1)` compares addresses, not C strings, always returns false. Strings in C++ are std::string, not arrays.

Comment: `if(cuv==cuv1)` doesn't do what you think it does.  Try rewriting this with [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: If you were to do this yourself, by hand, would you first write down the reverse of the word and compare the entire words, or would you just compare the characters at both ends directly?

Comment: @molbdnilo i would've compared the word and it's reverse, because I personally think that comparing the characters seems a bit more complicated.

Comment: @PaulSanders
how do I do that? I've recently learnt the char type and I am a "noob" at this type of things.

Comment: The first decision you need to make is whether you want to write C or C++. If you want to write C code then you can use plain `char` arrays and all the C library functions, like `strcmp`, `strcpy`, and others. But if your intent is to really write C++ code, you will want to use `std::string`, and all these C++ library's algorithms, instead of C library functions. There are multiple bugs in the shown code, including undefined behavior due to proper `'\0'` termination of C character strings, due to improper usage of C-style strings, which would no longer apply, by definition, in real C++ code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I want to write in C++ code, but our teacher has learned us to use char arrays in c++ and not the string type.;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method works fine, I've gave up trying to compare the words, so I compared the word's letters from start with those from the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char cuv[255]; cin>>cuv;
    int n = strlen(cuv);
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i!=strlen(cuv)/2;i++)
        if(cuv[i]!=cuv[n-i-1])
            k=1;
    if(k==0)
        cout<<"cuv pal";
    else
        cout<<"cuv != pal";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's a bad idea to call `strlen(cuv)` in a loop. Store the length in a variable before entering the loop instead

Comment: @phuclv i was in a rush and used strlen(cuv)/2 instead of n/2.

Answer (score 4):

This becomes much easier with `std::string` and `std::equal`:

```
std::string cuv = "ANNA";
return std::equal(std::begin(cuv), std::end(cuv), std::rbegin(cuv));
```

Or if for some reason you want to stick with C strings:

```
char cuv[255] = "ANNA";
int len = strlen(cuv);
return std::equal(cuv, cuv+len, std::reverse_iterator<char*>(cuv+len));
```

Answer (score -2):

problem is with this statement

cuv1[strlen(cuv1)+1]='\0'

Change this to

cuv1[strlen(cuv1)]='\0';

Comment: No, that's not it.

Comment: if you can call `strlen(cuv1)` the `cuv1` is already a null terminated string and adding a null terminator is pointless

Comment: Except that, @phuclv, it's not null-terminated.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik and in that case you can't call `strlen` to get the length

Comment: That is absolutely, 100%, guaranteed, true.